# Another 14.04 log in problem

Tags: 14.04

So I decided to take the plunge and upgrade my 12.04 system to 14.04 (the keyboard and mouse stopped working!) Now, when I log in on the greeter screen (spots bad passwords OK), I sometimes get a system error dialog or the screen just displays the wallpaper and nothing else happens, the system hangs.

I've spent sixish hours trying to fix this, searching forums and this site for solutions and tried many things, none of which worked and some even made it worse.

Apart from the hanging, I have no idea what's wrong. So this question isn't about fixing the problem, the question is: how do I find out why it's hanging? Once I know the 'why' I can use that to find an appropriate 'fix', at the moment I'm a bit in the dark.

Comment: Does it also happen to other user accounts, like the guest account?

Comment: All existing accounts suffer this problem, haven't tried creating a new account though, but that would be via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Log files stored in `/var/log` are the first place to look for problems.

In this case however, I couldn't see anything in the log files to suggest what the problem was. I logged in using a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1) and then ran `startx` which displayed a message about `modprobe` being unable to find the nvidia kernel module. Installing the nvidia drivers I noticed that there was a message about being unable to build the module because there were no source files. I then did:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-<whatever the version was>
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-340
```

which then built the modules without any errors. Rebooting the system and the login worked!